Flexbox items in three columns
I have a flexbox container that will contain 5 or 6 items. flex-direction of the container will be set to row. What I want is to distribute those items like this: The first item should be the first column, the second item should be the second column, and the rest 2 or 3 items should altogether be the third column, much like a grid configuration.
Unfortunately I can't alter the HTML markup to add additional containers that will help me. It has to be done purely in CSS (if it can be achieved).
I played around a bit in a Flex generator, and this is the closest I went (which isn't even close)...


  .flex-container {

    display: flex;
    
    justify-content: flex-end;  
    /* flex-flow: row wrap; */ 
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 

    background-color: #bbdefb;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    gap: 5px;

  }

  .flex-container > div{
    background: #ffecb3;
    border: 3px solid #ffcc80;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  }


  .item1 { 
    /* flex:0 1 32%; */
    flex-basis:32%;
    align-self:auto;
  }
            
  .item2 { 
    /* flex:0 1 32%; */
    flex-basis:32%;
    align-self:auto;
  }
            
  .item3 { 
    /* flex:0 1 32%; */
    flex-basis:32%;
    align-self:flex-start;
  }
            
  .item4 { 
    /* flex:0 1 32%; */
    flex-basis:32%;
    align-self:flex-start;
  }
            
  .item5 { 
    /* flex:0 1 32%; */
    flex-basis:32%;
    align-self:flex-start;
  }
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item1">item 1</div>
    <div class="item2">item 2</div>
    <div class="item3">item 3</div>
    <div class="item4">item 4</div>
    <div class="item5">item 5</div>
</div>



Can someone please help me figure this out?

Do the columns have equal width?

No, they don't!

I mean, they could... I don't have a particular preference on this.

Think about a layout like this: https://en.raceroms.com/car/audi/q3/u8-mk1-9-2011-2014 But the third column would contain 3 items, not just 2.

The problem with my case is that they layout would be like <div class="container"><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div></div>

Do you absolutely need to use flexbox?

Please give me a moment. Some new data just came, and I will update the question!

This feels like a case  that would be easily solved with Grid

I'm not clear what layout you want - what is a 'column' here? How would the layout differ from 5 divs laid out in one row (e.g. inline-block or similar) perhaps with different margins.

@AHaworth take a look at this screenshot please https://prnt.sc/oIQl5OTHlk3L Following Unmitigated's approach below I was able to get the most part of what I want. All that's left is the two items in the rightmost column to go up, just underneath the first item of the column...

Thanks for the picture - that makes it much clearer. I have a posted an answer based on the content of that picture to give an idea of what can be achieved with a simple grid.

You could use CSS grid and place all children after the first two in the third column.


.item {
  background: #ffecb3;
  border: 3px solid #ffcc80;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container > .item:nth-child(n + 3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>




As I said, I can't change the DOM. I don't have access to the HTML elements...

The HTML is the same, a container with 5 elements inside. You should be able to adjust the CSS to match your HTML classes (e.g. instead of doing .item, you could do .flex-container > div).

@AlvaroMontoro you are correct! With a quick glimpse I thought there was used additional HTML elements to group the 3rd, 4th, 5th items! I'll give it a try and report back!

@AlvaroMontoro for some reason (due to some inline CSS rule interfering) my second column has some awful gaps between its elements! What could be causing them? Other than that, indeed this seems like a legit solution to my problem!

@FayeD. That sounds like it should be a different question. It is related to this one, but it looks like some other code is the issue. It would be good to keep the problems separated so they are easier to identify.

I found what it is. The first column, the second column, and the top item of the third column have the same height! So the only few elements of the second column and the even fewer elements of the top item of the third column are aligned into that height... https://prnt.sc/iKYFKDdYFu8T

Exactly @AlvaroMontoro it's some other CSS rule that needs to be reset! What could be making thoes grid elements have equal heights? In Flexbox that would be align-items: flex-start; but I have totally zero knowledge on grids!

@FayeD. I'm glad you found the solution (if you want to learn more about grid, CSS-Tricks has a complete guide). And remember, if Unmitigated's answer helped you, don't forget to upvote and marked as the solution, so the question is complete.

OMG align-self:flex-start; seems to do the trick for grids (similar rule name)! But now I need to solve one last problem! Middle and bottom items of the third column won't appear until the height of the first column (which is the tallest)... https://prnt.sc/XNGAEk8WPH-_ Can you help me with this guys?

CSS-Grid with grid-auto-flow: column seems to do the trick


.item {
  background: #ffecb3;
  border: 3px solid #ffcc80;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  align-self: start;
  
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  height:40px;
}

.container > .item:nth-child(n + 3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  height: 60px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>




In your case Item 1 is the shortest! What if it is the tallest though? Doesn't it make the whole 1st row grow taller, thus pushing Item 4 after its height? I ask this because in my case, grid-auto-flow: column; didn't have any positive outcome... It only made second column (Item 2 in your example) "jump" just just underneath Item 1 in the first column, needing to define then what column it should be considered as with .item:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 2; }

Then what you want is probably not something that flexbox or CSS-Grid can do. Although old school I'd go with float.

You could have a 3 column, 3 row grid.
The first two items take up all 3 rows.
The items in the 3rd column take up one row each, and the rows are sized with the first 2 auto (ie whatever space is needed) and the last one 1fr (ie the remaining space).


<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  
  .container>div {
    border: 3px solid #ffcc80;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .item1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  }
  
  .item2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  }
  
  .item3 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  
  .item4 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  
  .item5 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  
  h3 {
    color: red;
  }
  
  h3,
  ul,
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>A1<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>Q2<br>R8<br>TTS<br></div>
  <div class="item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">
    <h3>Hybrid Gasoline</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Audi</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <h3>Gasoline</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Audi</li>
      <li>Audi</li>
      <li>Audi</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
    <h3>Diesel</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Audi</li>
      <li>Audi</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



